# How to push changes from GitHub Desktop to Cpanel

Tags: linux, git, github, repository, cpanel

Is it possible to directly push changes to a cpanel repository from GitHub desktop software. Or first the repository changes will be pushed to the online repository on github.com and then from there the cpanel will fetch the changes by clicking Update from Remote & Deploy HEAD Commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions), that is a process able to run on GitHub side, triggered by a push.

For example, a [deployment action](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#deployment), like one to [publish to Netlify](https://github.com/netlify/actions/tree/master/cli) or [zem](https://github.com/artemnovichkov/action-zem)

You would need to adapt such an action to push/publish to Cpanel, using [an API key](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/resources?topic=resources-externalapp#externalapp).

Comment: Sir, that means there is no in-built facility in GitHub Desktop client to directly push changes to cpanel. If no then what is the SSH key used for ? I will have to manually do the push process.......like currently i do it like this ------------ 1. Push from Github desktop client  2. Click the button given in cpanel - "Update from Remote " -------3. Click the cpanel button  : "Deploy from HEAD commit"

Comment: Exactly: if you cannot push directly to CPanel, then a GitHub action could automate your current manual step of "Update from Remote"

Comment: so this feature of directly pushing to cpanel from Github Desktop client is lacking ?

Comment: @sqlchild It is lacking indeed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clone the remote repository on your cPanel account to your local computer. `git clone URL`
2. Create the `.cpanel.yml` file.
3. Add the cPanel-managed repository as a remote. `git remote add origin URL`
4. Push changes to the cPanel-managed repository. `git push -u origin HEAD`

For more information: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git+-+How+to+Set+Up+Deployment

Comment: But I want to use GitHub Desktop instead of using cmd commands. I don't want to type and run the commands, but I want to push from GUI Interface of GitHub Desktop for windows

Comment: This might help https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10113/2210/how-to-use-git-version-control-cpanel-plugin . There is a Git VErsion Control cPanel plugin that is available if you don't want to use the cmd commands.

Comment: I have already done that.......but is it possible via GitHub Desktop?

Comment: I usually use the cmd commands, I am not sure about that.. sorry @sqlchild

Comment: no issues....its great to have your reply and help....thanks  a lot for atleast posting some help out and contributing to StackOverflow...EVERY ANSWER MATTERS